# Cpp: using scoped resource without passing arguments around

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I've been struggling with a design problem in cpp for a while. I have a resource (In this scenario a configuration). This configuration is global, and it is initialized and cleared multiple times during the program execution (If it's cleared, there is no current configuration, and if something needs it will fail).

I want to use this configuration inside a class- but I do not want to pass it around as a parameter, since it will change dozens of functions, and complicate classes interfaces a lot (and sometimes it even might be a weird dependency, especially if some derived classes need it and some do not).

Now I use a weird singleton, that can be cleared and initialized, but the codebase grew, and it looks bad now

Pseudo code for demonstration:

```
Configuration::init(buffer);
SomeClass some_class(param1, param2);
some_class.do_dirty_work_using_the_configuration();
Configuration::clear()
```

This code is not RAII and I actually use a class to initialize and clear the configuration in the real implementation.

I heard the solution should be dependency injection, but as far as I know there is no good implementation for it in cpp

Thank you!

Comment: really thats not a use case for DI. A singleton is fine, in fact its a classic use case for it.

Comment: _it is initialized and cleared multiple times during the program execution_ Why?  If you could fix that then a singleton would be the idiomatic solution.

Comment: ... And if you can't, then it shouldn't be a global.

Comment: You said thing like “passing it around would make weird dependencies, but it _is_ a dependency. An explicit dependency, no matter how weird is better than an implicit hidden one. I would stay away from globals and from singletons, personally. You might have to rethink your designs, but the code will grow better.

Comment: You should also clarify if you’re looking for dependency injection or a ioc service. My gut tells me you’re asking for the latter. DI is good and you should be using it. DI works great in C++ and is built into the language.